# Kibana 5 : Sense plugin installation in windows

Tags: elasticsearch, sense, kibana-5

I'm trying to install the Sense plugin in Kibana 5.0.1 and I am using windows 7
As per the documentation I have used following commands

```
bin/kibana-plugin install <package name or URL>
```

I am getting follwing error:

1. Using Package name : kibana-plugin install sense

   D:\workplace\kibana-5.0.1-windows-x86\bin>kibana-plugin install sense
   Attempting to transfer from sense
   Attempting to transfer from https:/ /artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugin
   s/sense/sense-5.0.1.zip
   Error: Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT 184.73.171.14:443
   Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect
    ETIMEDOUT 184.73.171.14:443"
2. Using URL : https://download.elasticsearch.org/elastic/sense/sense-latest.tar.gz

   D:\workplace\kibana-5.0.1-windows-x86\bin>kibana-plugin install https ://download.elasticsearch.org/elastic/sense/sense-latest.tar.gz
   Attempting to transfer from https:// download.elasticsearch.org/elastic/sense/sen
   se-latest.tar.gz
   Error: Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT 174.129.17.230:443
   Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect
    ETIMEDOUT 174.129.17.230:443"
3. Using downloaded file

   D:\workplace\kibana-5.0.1-windows-x86\bin>kibana-plugin install file//D:/workpla
   ce/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz
   Attempting to transfer from file//D:/workplace/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz
   Attempting to transfer from https ://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugin
   s/file//D:/workplace/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz/file//D:/workplace/sense-2.0.0-bet
   a7.tar.gz-5.0.1.zip
   Error: Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT 23.21.105.204:443
   Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect
    ETIMEDOUT 23.21.105.204:443"

I am not able to find any solution for this. Anyone have solution please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try this : kibana plugin -i sense -u file://C:\Users\JP\Downloads\sense-2.0.0-beta2.tar.gz.  i got this from here https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5545

Comment: Yes, I have tried that first and this fails as Kibana 5 does not have a plugin command, then I found a kibana-plugin command. As per the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_installing_plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/elastic/sense

`HEADS UP: This repo is deprecated. Sense is now included as Console in Kibana 5.0. File issues over at elastic/kibana`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes Kibana-Console is same as Sense but I'm not able to upload JSON file using console. So to upload file I have now installed Curl in windows. Now I don't need Sense in Kibana 5.